# Why the interval is not saved after I close the app?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app. I want to save the `UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS` after I close the app but it does not work.

```
if (intervalSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
    UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
else if (intervalSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)
    UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 20000;
else if (intervalSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2)
    UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;
else
    UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 40000;
```

Comment: You need to save and restore this value, for example via SharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the `UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS` before you close the application. Try to use `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

Save the `UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS` after the user select a different interval:

```
editor.putLong("interval", UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

Read the `UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS` when you restart your application:

```
UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = sharedPref.getLong("interval", 10000);
```